# Complex Eloquent SQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to run in Laravel 5.5 the following query:

```
select `colours`.`id` AS `id`
     ,`colours`.`description` AS `description`
     ,`vehicle_colour_and_trims`.`colour_id` AS `colour_id`
     ,`colours`.`code` AS `code`
     ,`vehicle_options`.`basic_price` AS `basic_price`
     ,`vehicle_options`.`mrp` AS `mrp`
     ,`vehicle_options`.`vat` AS `vat` 
from ((`vehicle_colour_and_trims` 
join `colours` 
  on ((`vehicle_colour_and_trims`.`colour_id` = `colours`.`id`))) 
join `vehicle_options` 
  on ((`colours`.`option_id` = `vehicle_options`.`option_id`)))  
WHERE vehicle_colour_and_trims.vehicle_id = 116922 
group by `colours`.`code` 
order by `colours`.`description`
```

Is this something that is beyond Eloquent?

Comment: not sure why you need a group by w/o aggregation.

Comment: are you getting errors? results you do not expect?

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, your GROUP BY clause is likely to return erroneous and/or unexpected (i.e. indeterminate) results. Also, what's `vat`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform complex queries, laravel provides the query builder tool, you can use the table method on the DB facade to begin a query.

In your controller you would have to add the following line to use the DB facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

The query you want to perform would be constructed like this:

```
    $query = DB::table('vehicle_colour_and_trims')
             ->join('colours', 'vehicle_colour_and_trims.colour_id', '=','colours.id')
             ->join('vehicle_options', 'colours.option_id', '=','vehicle_options.option_id')      
             ->select('colours.id AS id',
                      'colours.description AS description',
                      'vehicle_colour_and_trims.colour_id AS colour_id', 
                      'colours.code AS code',
                      'vehicle_options.basic_price AS basic_price',
                      'vehicle_options.mrp AS mrp',
                      'vehicle_options.vat AS vat')
             ->where('vehicle_colour_and_trims.vehicle_id','=', 116922)
             ->groupBy('colours.code')
             ->orderBy('colours.description', 'desc')
             ->get();
```

you can read more about query builder in the laravel documentation

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries

With this query the SQLSTATE [42000] error occurs because in mysql ** sql_mode = ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY ** is enabled by default, which means that MySQL rejects queries for which the selection list, HAVING condition or ORDER BY refer to non-aggregated columns that are not named in the GROUP BY clause or functionally dependent on them.

In order to add columns to the selection list without having to add them to the GROUP_BY clause, you have to use the function **ANY_VALUE()** for each of the columns that do not have to be present in the clause, try this:

```
$query = DB::table('vehicle_colour_and_trims')
         ->join('colours', 'vehicle_colour_and_trims.colour_id', '=','colours.id')
         ->join('vehicle_options', 'colours.option_id', '=','vehicle_options.option_id')      
         ->select(DB::raw('ANY_VALUE(colours.id) AS id,
                           ANY_VALUE(colours.description) AS description,
                           ANY_VALUE(vehicle_colour_and_trims.colour_id) AS colour_id,
                           colours.code AS code,
                           ANY_VALUE(vehicle_options.basic_price) AS basic_price,
                           ANY_VALUE(vehicle_options.mrp) AS mrp,
                           ANY_VALUE(vehicle_options.vat) AS vat'))
         ->where('vehicle_colour_and_trims.vehicle_id','=', 116922)
         ->groupBy('colours.code')
         ->orderBy('colours.description', 'desc')
         ->get();
```

The DB::raw() function allows you to create raw expressions

More info:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: I have an error

    SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column  'cl24-ids.colours.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by